# Probability of matching 4 answers to 4 questions

Tags: probability

In an examination a candidate is given the four answers to four questions but is not told which answer applies to which question. If a candidate guesses at random where the four answers go, calculate the probability of $0$ correct answers.

My attempt:
$(3/4)(2/3)(1/2)= 1/4$ which doesn't match the correct answer $(3/8)$

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: these go by the name [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).  Note:  in that link, they happen to go through the $n=4$ case explicitly, which is precisely what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I think your reasoning went:

On the first question, there are 4 possible answers, and 3 of them are wrong. So there is a $\frac{3}{4}$ chance of answering the first question wrong.

On the second question, now that the candidate has already gotten rid of an answer, there are 3 possible answers, and 2 of them are wrong, so there is a $\frac{2}{3}$ chance of answering the second question wrong. And so on with the third and fourth questions.

Here's where the logic breaks down: The probability that the candidate answers the second question incorrectly depends on which (incorrect) answer the candidate gave for the first question, i.e. the events of answering the first and second questions incorrectly, respectively, are **not independent**. If the candidate gave the answer to question 2 as the answer to question 1, then there is no chance that the answer the candidate gives for question 2 can be correct. If not, then there is a chance the answer given can be correct.

Instead, you will have to look at the $4!$ permutations of the 4 answers and determine which permutations have no fixed elements. The other answers do a good job of describing how to calculate the number of such permutations.

Comment: Great explanation of the OP's attempt.  I wouldn't have seen that!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

There's one case where they're all correct.

No cases with (exactly) three correct.  If three are correct, so is the fourth.

Six cases with two correct (pick two to be correct, then make the other two incorrect).  (You can choose the two correct ones $_4C_2 = 6$ ways.)

With one correct, let's say the answers are $ABCD$ in order.  You can have $ACDB$ or $ADBC$ with $A$ correct and all others incorrect.  All other arrangements of $BCD$ have at least one correct among them if $A$ is correct.  Repeating for each letter gives $8$ cases.

So that's $1+6+8 = 15$ cases where at least one is correct, that leaves $9$ with all incorrect, for a probability of $9/24 = 3/8$.

Comment: Thanks! That's my second approach to the problem lol, but I was just curious of how to obtain the answer without calculating the rest of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

There are $24$ permutations of four answers. If these answers are labelled $1,2,3,$ and $4$ where $1234$ is the correct assignment of answers, we want permutations with no fixed points (also called [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)) i.e. $\sigma(i)\neq i$ for all $i$. These permutations are $$2143, 2341, 2413, 3142, 3412, 3421, 4123, 4312, 4321.$$ Hence the probability is $9/24$ or $3/8$.

Answer (score 0):

There are $24$ possible ways to order the questions.

For example:

$1,2,3,4$ (all of them are correct) or $2,3,1,4$ (only the last one is correct).

You want to find how many permutations of $1,2,3,4$ satisfy that no number ends in its "correct" position.

They are $9$.

They are the following:

$ 2 1 4 3 $

$ 2 3 4 1 $

$ 2 4 1 3 $

$ 3 1 4 2 $

$ 3 4 1 2 $

$ 3 4 2 1 $

$ 4 1 2 3 $

$ 4 3 1 2 $

$ 4 3 2 1 $

Therefore the answer is $\frac{9}{24}=\frac{3}{8}$.

---

If you want to solve the problem in general, for $n$ questions, then the answer is $\frac{!n}{n!}$, where $!n$ is $n$ subfactorial. The limit of this number is $\frac{1}{e}$ when $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation for the general case :)

Comment: You are welcome, it was a pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

It is the symmetric group on 4 letters.

There are 24 elements to the group.

there is 1 way to get all 4 correct.(identity)

there are 6 simple transpositions (2 correct, 2 incorrect)

There are 8 3 -cycles (1 correct, 3 incorrect)

there are 6, 4-cycles and 3, double transpostions (0 correct)

9/24